# assign jQuery function to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is this one:

```
var hlpOpenPopup = function(open_id,close_id, animation){

    if(typeof animation === 'undefined'){
        animation = jQuery.slideDown;
    }

    jQuery(open_id).animation();
}
```

I am trying to set slideDown method as default if function hlpOpenPopup is called without animation argument.
SlideDown is a jQuery method, and my code doesn't work because jQuery.slideDown equals `undefined`

Comment: Set it to a string and access with brackets?

Comment: `slideDown` is actually a property of `jQuery.fn`

Comment: If I do `animation = jQuery.fn.slideDown` and then I call it with `jQuery(open_id).animation();` it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var hlpOpenPopup = function(open_id,close_id, animation){

    if(typeof animation === 'undefined'){
        animation = 'slideDown';
    }

    jQuery(open_id)[animation]();
}
```

When calling the function, pass the name of the animation to use as a string in the `animation` argument (e.g. `hlpOpenPopup("#id1", "#id2", "slideUp")`).

Comment: Yes, this works but my question asks how to assign to a variable a reference to a jQuery method